# Flex RadioButton label won't truncate

Tags: apache-flex, radio-button, label, truncate, flex-spark

I have RadioButton, just one singular RadioButton not in a Group or anything like that. I set it's width to 100. I then give it a label which is much longer than 100px. Also, in the Skin for this RadioButton I have the Label just being a subclass of Spark Label in which I set the showTruncationTip of TextBase to true because that's the behavior I'm looking for.

So the Label should truncate, should it not? Instead, my label shows the entire thing not truncated at 100.

However, if I do the same exact thing but with a CheckBox, it works correctly.

Here's the MXML for my RadioButton:

```
<myNameSpace:RadioButton  width="100" id="radBtn1" value="1" label="Yooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo o" />
```

And here is the relevant part in the Skin:

```
<s:HGroup width="100%" left="18" gap="5" y="{ icon.height === 0 ? 2 : -4}" verticalAlign="middle">
                <myNameSpace:Icon id="icon"/>
                <myNameSpace:Label id="labelDisplay"
                                     textAlign="start"
                                     verticalAlign="middle"
                                     maxDisplayedLines="1"/>
      </s:HGroup>
```

And just to show you that it's basically the same, here's my CheckBox Code:

```
<myNameSpace:CheckBox id="checkBox" width="100" label="Click here to turn this On"/>
```

And the Skin:

```
<s:HGroup left="18" right="0" top="3" bottom="3" verticalCenter="0" verticalAlign="middle" width="100%">
    <myNameSpace:Label id="labelDisplay"
             textAlign="start"
             maxDisplayedLines="{getStyle('wrapLabel') ?  -1 : 1}"
             width="100%" />
    <myNameSpace:Label id="readOnlyLabel" includeIn="readOnly"/>
</s:HGroup>
```

So what's going on? I even tried just doing this with a normal Spark RadioButton but even that won't truncate.

**Edit:**

Well from what I'm finding out from trial and error, it seems that mx RadioButton will truncate correctly, but Spark will not. My RadioButton extends from Spark so it also will not truncate.

So question now is: How can I make a Spark RadioButton's label truncate? As you can see from the Skin in the original post, I do have maxDisplayedLines set to 1, but it still won't show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give the `Label` a width, it will truncate the text. Notice in your check box case, the label has `width="100%"`, but there's no width in the radio button case.

Comment: Yeah, in the skin. Truncation is like word wrapping, the text objects need to know when to start doing it by having a some sort of width.

Comment: Well how about that, it worked. Thanks a lot, that was easy enough.